# Nexus 3064 Sflow performance

Tags: nx-os

We have a C3064PQ-10Gx with 10-12gbps bps and around 4m pps and we have in mind to enable sFlow to analyze the traffic, so i want to make sure if i enable sFlow it will not impact on the nexus CPU normally or while i am under DDOS Attacks? because it should process many bps pps,
Thank you.

Comment: It will affect the CPU but not excessively. Forwarding is done in hardware so that won’t be affected

Comment: so do you think that i am safe without put cpu under pressure if i run sflow for 10-12gbps bps and 4-5m pps ?

Comment: Depends on how fast you sample.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The impact on the CPU depends on the sflow sampling rate. You can adjust the sampling rate and watch the CPU usage. If it gets too high, lower the sampling rate.